# guard error ActionController::UrlGenerationError:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, guard

I am starting to write tests for my rails application, and plan to write them prior to building the actual pages, but I am having trouble. I have searched stack overflow and google and have tried several things. The route is specified in my routes.rb file and looks like:

```
resources :welcome
```

I have the following written into my test code.

```
require 'rails_helper'
require 'spec_helper'

RSpec.describe "Welcomes", type: :request do
  it "checks the welcome page." do
    visit welcome_path
  end
end
```

I get the following Error from guard:

```
Failures:

  1) Welcomes checks the welcome page.
     Failure/Error: visit welcome_path
     ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
       No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"welcome"} missing required keys: [:id]
     # ./spec/requests/welcomes_spec.rb:6:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.00347 seconds (files took 1.61 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/requests/welcomes_spec.rb:5 # Welcomes checks the welcome page.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `visit welcome_path` to `get '/welcome'`

Answer (score 0):

The `index` of a Rails `resources` route set is at `welcomes_path`. `welcome_path` would refer to a specific `Welcome` and requires an `:id` parameter.

If the welcome page is just a landing page and not actually a resource, you might just want `config/routes.rb` to contain:

```
get 'welcome', to: 'welcome#index`
```

The first `welcome` is the path (`host.com/welcome`), and the `to:` argument is `controller#action`.

The [Rails routing docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) are great. Give them a good read through if this didn't make sense.